# Extract everything between two strings in bash

Tags: bash, extract

I have a file with a structure

```
[Name]
Line 1

[Data]
Velocity v [ m s^-1 ], X [ m ], Y [ m ]
0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.08999997e-01
1.38282625e-03, 7.67676742e-04, 1.08999997e-01
2.76565249e-03, 1.53535348e-03, 1.08999997e-01
4.14847909e-03, 2.30303034e-03, 1.08999997e-01
5.53130498e-03, 3.07070697e-03, 1.08999997e-01
6.91413041e-03, 3.83838359e-03, 1.08999997e-01
[...]
-4.43599839e-03, 7.36970305e-02, 1.08999997e-01
-2.95729283e-03, 7.44647086e-02, 1.08999997e-01
-1.47858984e-03, 7.52323866e-02, 1.08999997e-01
0.00000000e+00, 7.60000646e-02, 1.08999997e-01

[Name]
Line 2

[Data]
Velocity v [ m s^-1 ], X [ m ], Y [ m ]
0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 2.17999995e-01
2.01415829e-03, 7.67676742e-04, 2.17999995e-01
[...]
```

And I want to extract those numbers between Line 1 and Line 2 with using a bash script.
How can I realize this?

Comment: Have you added `Line 1` and `Line 2` into your example to show us the range of lines, or are they really there? If they're not really there, how can we identify this specific section of the file?

Comment: Also, please edit you Q to show your required output, given that input. Use the `{}` tool at the top left of the edit box on selected text to format as code/data. Good luck.

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/7552): Are you actually after the `[Data]` block when `[Name]` is "Line 1" ? If yes, that's really a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -n '/Line 1/,/Line 2/p' filename
```

That will include the "line [12]" lines, but those can be easily removed.

Comment: `sed -n '/Line 1/,/Line 2/p' filename | tail -n +1 | head -n -1`